# Log Parsing/Analysing

Tags: logging, text-parsing

I am looking for a Java or Python based solution to parse a custom log file and prepare custom report dashboard.

Is there any way I can read that log file as a flat file database ?

Answer (score 1):

try this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

it's very good and pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

A log file is not a database, but you can read one with Python doing:

```
logFile = file('/path/to/file')
for line in logFile:
    # do something with the line, maybe some regex matching?
    ...
```